# Execute htmlspecialchars on a multi level array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to find a way to loop through all my data and remove all the HTML special characters. The problem is my data can have values that are arrays which can themselve have 5 or 6 sub arrays.  Could someone please help me with a good method to do this. This is the code I have been working with so far but it skips all the sub arrays values.

```
    foreach($view['data'] as $key => $value){
        // Check if Array
        if(!is_array($value)){
            $view['data'][$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you want a **recursive function**? In your specific case, if you have 5 to 6 sub arrays (therefore dynamic arrays), you have to use a recursive function to loop between them. Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `array_walk_recursive()` function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

```
array_walk_recursive($view['data'], function(&$item) {
  $item = htmlspecialchars($item);
});
```

Comment: you forgot the return statement.

Comment: I've forgotten the `&` of the function parameter. You don't need a return statement see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#106146

Answer (score -1):

You want [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Like this:

```
 array_walk_recursive($view['data'], function($el){
     return htmlspecialchars($el);
 });
```